# Limiting records in recursion

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
15:     - for findlist in @user.findlists
16:       =findlist.name
17:       %div
18:       - for product in findlist.products
19:         = image_tag(product.photo.url(:small))
```

I am looking at line 18. Is there a way to limit findlist.products to only 3 records without putting some kind of counter?

> I am using Rails 2.3.8

Comment: I can't answer this question because my answer keeps referring to itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is limited a method in your model? you can always append a find method in rails 3 with limit(n)

so in your case if that is a find method

```
for product in findlist.products.limit(3)
```

if you're not using rails 3:

```
for product in findlist.products.find(:all, :limit => 3)
```

Comment: I've tried that but I think it's a Rails 3 thing and I am using 2.3.8

Comment: I've edited `limited`. I was trying to do something and pasted it along.

Comment: Well, it didn't work. I'd be using take(3) for now but I will still look into finding another option.